# Insertion SQL and NOT NULL values

Tags: sql, insertion

I've created a table schema and specified that for some attributes, values cannot be null. For one column of this table, values are to be imported from a column of some another table but the problem i am facing is that when i use insert statement to copy values from that column  of another table to the column of this newly created table, the attributes of this new column start screaming because they kind of have a constraint on them that while insertion their values cannot be NULL! 
How do i cope with this?

One solution is that for other attributes, just for time being, i can state that null values can be accommodated so that i can successfully import values from column of other table and then later on put condition on the remaining attributes that values are not be NULL. But how do i do do this?

Comment: can you post the code you are using for the insertion and also what sql engine you are using?

Comment: you're trying to put null value in non null column, what do you expect to see in result? such row should be either skipped or null value should be replaced with some real one

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `NULL` to some `DEFAULT` values while importing.

I am not sure which DB engine you are using, in mysql:
Use something like `IFNULL(column_name, "")`.

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Answer (score -1):

You may simply be looking for the `default` clause.  When you define a column, you can specify;

```
intcol int not null default 0
```

If the column is not specified for an insert, then it will default to 0.  In some databases, if a `NULL` value is supplied, it will also get the default value.